# Generate CMSSignedData with no private key in JAVA

Tags: java, bouncycastle, smime

I'm currently trying to generate a `CMSSignedData` using only a certificate data and a signed data which is generated from an external software (so I don't have access to the private key and the signature generation is transparent for me). What i need is the encoded data to add it to a `SMIME` signature content.

Searching on web I find out a solution with `BouncyCastle` that uses the private key and the data to be signed to get a `CMSSignedData`. But it don't fix to my problem because I don't have access to private key and the signature is already generated.

Is there any way to create a CMS object using only the certificate data, the public key and the previously generated signature?

Any approach or library i can use or try?

Answer (score 0):

CMS (Cryptographic Message Syntax) is specified in [RFC 5652](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652). The SignedData type is an ASN.1 structure, which basically consists of the signed data (*encapContentInfo*), the signature certificate (and chain) and the signature itself (part of *signerInfos*):

```
SignedData ::= SEQUENCE {
    version CMSVersion,
    digestAlgorithms DigestAlgorithmIdentifiers,
    encapContentInfo EncapsulatedContentInfo,
    certificates [0] IMPLICIT CertificateSet OPTIONAL,
    crls [1] IMPLICIT RevocationInfoChoices OPTIONAL,
    signerInfos SignerInfos }

SignerInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
    version CMSVersion,
    sid SignerIdentifier,
    digestAlgorithm DigestAlgorithmIdentifier,
    signedAttrs [0] IMPLICIT SignedAttributes OPTIONAL,
    signatureAlgorithm SignatureAlgorithmIdentifier,
    signature SignatureValue,
    unsignedAttrs [1] IMPLICIT UnsignedAttributes OPTIONAL }
```

So, what you have to do now is to create this ASN.1 structure out of the data you have. If you don't already know the algorithms that were used for the signature, you can certainly obtain that information from the operator of the external signing software.

Bouncy Castle is generally a good choice for ASN.1 encoding and in addition you can use the source code of Bouncy Castle that normally creates a `CMSSignedData` object ([CMSSignedDataGenerator](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/pkix/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSSignedDataGenerator.java)) as a template.

Comment: This is a very good approach. I started doing what you said about using the Bouncy Castle classes as template but I found it a little bit difficult. Then I found a library called [j4sign](http://j4sign.sourceforge.net/) that implements just what I need (and it uses Bouncy Castle).

Comment: @banshee20 Yeah, BC is not exactly easy to use, the code is not very well documented and hard to read if you have little experience with ASN.1. On the other hand, it's comprehensive, well tested and you can do pretty much everything with it if you know how. Anyway, I'm glad you've found an easy solution for your problem.

Comment: I also need to do this. Did you use the ExternalSignatureCMSSignedDataGenerator to accomplish this? Thanks